# GAE Android Connected Project JDO Primary key

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, primary-key, jdo

I have been trying to create a GAE to get and insert data into my Android Application. I used the Eclipse wizard to create both projects (app engine connected android project). I am using JDO and trying to create unique primary keys but it doesn't seem to be doing it for me and I think that it should although i'm probably wrong. The server keeps popping out messages that the primary key should not be 0. Im new to this and was testing it out. Here is the code I feel is relevant (please let me know if more is needed). As to my understanding, it should be getting its key when the server calls makepersistant().

```
@ApiMethod(name = "insertTrack")
public Track insertTrack(Track track) {
    PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        if (containsTrack(track)) {
            throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
        }
        mgr.makePersistent(track);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return track;
}
```

This is what my app is calling:

```
public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

          Trackendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Trackendpoint.Builder(
          AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
          new JacksonFactory(),
          new HttpRequestInitializer() {
          public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
          });
  Trackendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
  endpointBuilder).build();
  try {
      Track track = new Track();
      track.setName("1");
      track.setDesc("First Track on Server");          
      Track result = endpoint.insertTrack(track).execute();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
      return (long) 0;
    }
}
```

And the JDO

```
public class Track {
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private long trackID;
private String name;
private String desc;
```

Any help leading me in the right direction would be awesome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need a couple of things from you: 1) Can you post the stack trace if any of the server 2) Please post the code of containsTrack(track) method.

Comment: FYI, that is tested in Google's plugin here https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/tests/com/google/appengine/datanucleus/jdo/JDOPrimaryKeyTest.java with this model class https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/tests/com/google/appengine/datanucleus/test/jdo/HasLongPrimitivePkJDO.java so you can see what you've done differently

Comment: I got it working from 3 hours of research and a couple of quick fixes. Thanks!